# How to stay on the same tab after submitting a form in accordion using jquery

Tags: asp.net, redirect, jquery-ui-accordion

I just want to stay in the same tab after submitting the form.

Here is the script:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", navigation: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have corrected it using this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAccordionIndex" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

Put this in your coding and change the script as follows

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
header: "h3",
autoHeight: false,
event: "mousedown",
active: activeIndex,
ui: "Admin.aspx",
change: function (event, ui) {
var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
$('#<% =hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val(index);
}
});
```

Comment: here ui means yor web form name